# form_for is giving me the wrong url for path_prefixes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a problem with the form_for method in Rails. It is behaving strangely.

I have a route with a path prefix, something like:

```
map.resources :beers, :path_prefix => '/:brewery'
```

And I have a form like this (@beer.brewery is a string, just the name of the brewery):

```
<% form_for @beer, :url => { :brewery => @beer.brewery } do |form|
--some fields
<% end %>
```

It will set the action of the form to this for a new record.

```
/brewery_name/beers/new
```

and this for an existing record.

```
/brewery_name/beers/1/edit
```

Anyone knows why this happens or how to fix it?

--edit--

Right now I am solving this like this (for a new record):

```
 <% form_for @beer, :url => beers_path(@beer.brewery) do |form| %>
```

and (for an edited record)

```
<% form_for @beer, :url => beer_path(@beer.brewery, @beer) do |form| %>
```

But I want to do it the same way for new and edit, if it is possible.

Cheers,
Thijs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want this to go to a brewery's beer. In that case:

```
<% form_for [@beer.brewery, @beer] do |f| %>
  -- some fields
<% end %>
```

By providing an Array as the first argument to `form_for` it will generate a nested resource.

Comment: No, that is not the case. The brewery part is for the prefix, not for a nested resource.